# Nested tabs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on tabs. Multiple tabs on the same page are working fine now I'm trying to add tab inside the tab. Nested Sub tabs default current active class is not coming i have tried using `$(this).parent()` and `$(this).closest()` in jquery but not achieve the result.Here I was not used any id's because I want multiple tabs on the same page which is coming dynamically.  Can anyone point me in the right direction nested tab default active tab and I have added the current class in HTML but because of for each loop current class is removing. How to target only the current parent tab, not sub nested tabs.

Multiple tabs achieved

```js
function atscTabs() {
  $('.at-tabs').each(function(index, item) {
    var $mainContainer = $(this);
    var $menuContainer = $(this).find('.at-tabs-nav__item');
    var $label = $(this).find('.at-tab-__title_text');
    var $content = $(this).find('.at-tabs-content__item');

    $content.hide();
    $label.each(function(idx, ele) {
      $(this).attr('data-target', idx)
    });
    $($menuContainer[0], $label[0]).addClass('current');
    $($content[0]).show();

    $menuContainer.click(function(ele) {
      $($mainContainer).find('.current').removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');
      $(this).find('.at-tab-__title_text').addClass('current');
      $($mainContainer).find('.at-tabs-content .at-tabs-content__item').hide().eq(parseInt($(this).find('[data-target]').attr('data-target'))).show();
    });
  });
}

atscTabs();
```

```css
.tab-warp {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.at-tabs-nav__item.current {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #3c98ff;
}

.at-tabs-nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 28px 0px;
}

a.at-tabs-title {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
}

.current a.at-tabs-title {
  color: #fff;
}

.at-tabs-nav__item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

.at-tabs-content {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

hr {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="at-tabs-c2a3d74" class="at-tabs">
  <div class="at-tabs-nav">

    <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
      <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
        <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
          <span class="at-tab-__title_text current">Tab #1</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
      <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
        <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
          <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #2</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
      <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
        <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
          <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #3</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="at-tabs-content">
    <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
      I am item content. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="at-tabs-c2a3d74" class="at-tabs">
  <div class="at-tabs-nav">

    <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
      <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
        <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
          <span class="at-tab-__title_text current">Tab #1</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
      <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
        <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
          <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #2</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
      <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
        <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
          <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #3</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="at-tabs-content">
    <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
      I am item content. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Trying to do Nested Tabs

```js
function atscTabs() {
  $('.at-tabs').each(function(index, item) {
    var $mainContainer = $(this);
    var $menuContainer = $(this).find('.at-tabs-nav__item');
    var $label = $(this).find('.at-tab-__title_text');
    var $content = $(this).find('.at-tabs-content__item');

    $content.hide();
    $label.each(function(idx, ele) {
      $(this).attr('data-target', idx)
    });
    $($menuContainer[0], $label[0]).addClass('current');
    $($content[0]).show();

    $menuContainer.click(function(ele) {
      $($mainContainer).find('.current').removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');
      $(this).find('.at-tab-__title_text').addClass('current');
      $($mainContainer).find('.at-tabs-content .at-tabs-content__item').hide().eq(parseInt($(this).find('[data-target]').attr('data-target'))).show();
    });
  });
}

atscTabs();
```

```css
.tab-warp {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.at-tabs-nav__item.current {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #3c98ff;
}

.at-tabs-nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 28px 0px;
}

a.at-tabs-title {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
}

.current a.at-tabs-title {
  color: #fff;
}

.at-tabs-nav__item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

.at-tabs-content {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

hr {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="at-tabs-c2a3d74" class="at-tabs">
  <div class="at-tabs-nav">

    <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
      <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
        <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
          <span class="at-tab-__title_text current">Tab #1</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
      <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
        <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
          <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #2</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
      <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
        <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
          <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #3</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="at-tabs-content">
    <div class="at-tabs-content__item">


      <div id="at-tabs-c2a3d74" class="at-tabs">
        <div class="at-tabs-nav">

          <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
            <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
              <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
                <span class="at-tab-__title_text current">Tab #1</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
            <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
              <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
                <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #2</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
            <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
              <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
                <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #3</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="at-tabs-content">
          <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
          </div>
          <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
            ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
          </div>
          <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
            I am item content. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
      I am item content. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything right, except scopes, your click event scopes are applied to all the elements, you need to limit the scope to the `.at-tabs`

Like this:

```
$(this).find('.at-tabs-nav__item').click(function(ele) {   
      $(this).closest('.at-tabs').find('.current').removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');
      $(this).find('.at-tab-__title_text').addClass('current');
      $(this).closest('.at-tabs').find('.at-tabs-content__item').hide().eq(parseInt($(this).find('[data-target]').attr('data-target'))).show();
    });
  });
```

Full example:

```js
function atscTabs() {
  $('.at-tabs').each(function(index, item) {

    var $mainContainer = $(this);
    var $menuContainer = $(this).find('.at-tabs-nav__item');
    var $label = $(this).find('.at-tab-__title_text');
    var $content = $(this).find('.at-tabs-content__item');

    $content.hide();
    $label.each(function(idx, ele) {
      $(this).attr('data-target', idx)
    });
    $($menuContainer[0], $label[0]).addClass('current');
    $($content[0]).show();

    $(this).find('.at-tabs-nav__item').click(function(ele) {
      $(this).closest('.at-tabs').find('.current').removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');
      $(this).find('.at-tab-__title_text').addClass('current');
      $(this).closest('.at-tabs').find('.at-tabs-content__item').hide().eq(parseInt($(this).find('[data-target]').attr('data-target'))).show();
    });
  });
}

atscTabs();
```

```css
.tab-warp {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.at-tabs-nav__item.current {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #3c98ff;
}

.at-tabs-nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 28px 0px;
}

a.at-tabs-title {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
}

.current a.at-tabs-title {
  color: #fff;
}

.at-tabs-nav__item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

.at-tabs-content {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

hr {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="at-tabs-c2a3d74" class="at-tabs">
  <div class="at-tabs-nav">

    <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
      <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
        <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
          <span class="at-tab-__title_text current">Tab #1</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
      <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
        <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
          <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #2</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
      <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
        <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
          <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #3</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="at-tabs-content">
    <div class="at-tabs-content__item">

      <div id="at-tabs-c2a3d74" class="at-tabs">
        <div class="at-tabs-nav">

          <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
            <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
              <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
                <span class="at-tab-__title_text current">Tab #1</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
            <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
              <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
                <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #2</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="at-tabs-nav__item">
            <a class="at-tabs-title" href="#">
              <div class="at-title-text-wrapper">
                <span class="at-tab-__title_text">Tab #3</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="at-tabs-content">
          <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
          </div>
          <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
            ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
          </div>
          <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
            I am item content. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
    </div>
    <div class="at-tabs-content__item">
      I am item content. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MahsaHassankashi this one is good too. this requires jquery-ui to be added.

Comment: @Husna glad that helps.

Comment: @Just code Have you see in the first tab tab2 and tab3 is not working. Can you please check this I have tried.

Comment: @Justcode In the tab1. tab2 and tab3 content are not showing in your code also.

Comment: please understand my code and you can change accordingly

Comment: @Justcode Can you please check this https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/JeBaWw?editors=1010 same code I'm using here.

Comment: @Justcode I have written inside a tab in which tab content is not showing. Like this  `This tab content is not coming` this means the last tab2 and tab3 content is not coming only current class is added.

Comment: @Husna please check this: https://codepen.io/dholakiyaankit/pen/KrjPKr?editors=1010

Comment: @Justcode yeah this what exactly I trying to do thanks.

Comment: @Justcode nested tab default tab1 active current class is not showing can you help me out I have tried using parent(); also but not working in html already written current .https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/YRozVJ?editors=1010